# Single expand accordian with plus minus button

Tags: jquery

If i click the first tab it will expand, if I click on another tab the first tab will collapse but the icon is not changing to minus. This is my fiddle link

```
{http://jsfiddle.net/kirandas82/4jaSL/16/}
```

Comment: You should provide the code from the external site (i.e. jsfiddle) in your question just in case the site were to go down

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use [jquery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) instead of reinventing the wheel.... easy to use..and customize